How to build level, load-bearing platform on non-level piece of yard
I want to build a level platform on a corner of my yard under a 8x8ft tent canopy. The area of yard is not dramatically sloped but not perfectly level either. The platform will need to be load-bearing, strong enough to support my (relatively small) workbench and tools. Will use the outdoor space for DIY and hobbyist woodworking projects. Cost and ease of constructing are the other 2 important factors for me. Any help much appreciated! (Addendum: pics below show canopy with legs partially collapsed. When fully deployed, get a height clearance of about 83in from ground.)



You either level out the ground, or find the ground high point and build a level platform from that point.  Adjusting the supports height as you go.  If the tent/cover cannot be raised, then levelling out the ground might keep you from bending over too much.

You want to build a deck.

Are you going to leave your workbench and tools permanently under this canopy?  I don't think they will last long!   Or bring them out from a shed whenever you need them?  If so, how will you bring them out?   I like the idea of an outdoor workshop  but it seems impractical to have it in a location away from dry storage.

Broad question begets broad answer. Anything from:

"Dump load of gravel, rake level and tamp."

Through:

"Build a deck, using normal deck-building techniques suitable for
your climate (frost depth matters, normally, if you want it to stay
level.)

On up to:

"Pour a concrete slab using normal techniques suitable for your
climate (again, frost depth matters.)

In most areas those are less expensive to most expensive options, in that order. The first one normally won't require permits or change your assessment for taxes, the others may do both, depending on your area. They might also be prohibited in some areas due to "set-back" requirements if the fence is on/near the property line.

Build a floating deck. This is basically specially shaped blocks:

which are designed so they can fit 2x lumber across or 4x4 posts in the middle. You set up the blocks across the lawn. The ones that are lower get chunks of 4x4 cut to the right height. Then you build a deck frame out of 2x lumber and deck boards on top.
The advantage of a floating deck is that it does not require footings. The disadvantage is that there could be some movement if the ground shifts during freeze/thaw cycles, but for this type of use it works very well.

Ensure local code allows it. I attempted to build a floating deck next to my house, but even our little town with pretty lax zoning wouldn't allow it.

My county, which tends to be strict on things, allows up to 200 square feet floating deck, so that's what I built.

You still got my +1, OP will just have to check...

A workshop on a typical deck with gaps between the boards will be a small parts black hole.  You'll want to cover it with some outdoor flooring, maybe a thin artificial turf mat that can be hosed down and will also stop little things from rolling too far.
